# Could a key derivation function be used to encrypt data with a weaker key?

Tags: encryption, key-derivation, password-based-encryption

To allow the key to be more easily remembered.

Example:
To encrypt a hard drive without having a remember a key with 128 bits of entropy.

From what I find they seem mostly used to hash passwords so the password database is more resistant to brute force in the case it's compromised. (compared to using a regular hash function)

So I'm not sure that the use case that I mentioned would be safe.

Comment: Sure you can (and should) apply a strong PBKDF when using passwords. This is standard practice for Full Disk Encryption to recover the full entropy bulk encryption keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with caveats.

Yes, because this is the entire stated point of password-based key derivation functions (e.g., PBKDF2 or scrypt). The caveat is that more iterations only get you so much; 100,000 iterations is only enough to increase "effective" entropy by a little over 16 bits ($100,000 \approx 2^{16}$) — to match a real 128-bit key, you'd need a password with 112 bits of entropy, which is an impractical 19-character alphanumeric password.

One approach without this caveat is to use a PBKDF to derive an actual encryption key from a key and password; this has the benefits of both systems. There's a real 128-bit (or 256-bit) secret that protects the data, which is typically invisible to a user, but you require a password to access and use that key.

Comment: > There's a real 128-bit (or 256-bit) secret that protects the data, which is typically invisible to a user, but you require a password to access and use that key.

Instead to brute forcing the data, an attacker would brute force the key, what would it change?

Comment: Brute forcing data doesn't make sense, and brute forcing a 128-bit key is outside of the realm of plausibility. The point of such a scheme is that an attacker can't simply guess passwords without *also* having the secret key.

Comment: ok, I didn't understood that encryption_key = KDF(password, key). By brute forcing the data I meant that the attacker will brute force the key to decrypt the data. But that's invalidated by because I misunderstood what you explained. Can you confirm that you proposal is only useful when the attacker can access only the data and not the key? And what could be such situations?

Comment: No cryptosystem is useful if an attacker can access the data and key.

Comment: «derive an actual encryption key from a key and password»

Then the key must be stored in the same support as the data. I don't get the benefit.

Comment: For example, this ties decryption to a particular device. iOS and OSX use this for their full-disk encryption, which is why the FBI requires Apple's assistance to unlock the San Bernardino shooter's iPhone.

Comment: In that case the FBI wouldn't brute force the encrypted partition directly (lets say the key have a 128 bits length) but they could brute force the encrypted key as the passphrase should have much less than 128 bits of entropy (even with additional bits provided by the KDF). So what is the benefit of storing an encrypted key instead of decrypting the data with KDF(passphrase)

Comment: Actually it would allow to change the passphrase without needing to encrypt the whole drive.

Comment: They can't brute force the encrypted key, because the encrypted key is stored in hardware specifically designed to resist extraction of the key. Multiple failed attempts at submitting passwords result in permanent deletion of the key.

Comment: Oh I get the point now! Thanks a lot for your time and knowledge :)